# Debugging React/Node back-end

Tags: node.js, reactjs, intellij-idea, webpack, babeljs

So, here's the situation. I've recently "inherited" a decent sized web application, built using React (and Redux) and compiled using webpack/babel. Two files are generated, app.js and server.js, both of which run on Node.

The original developer of the project was mostly "winging it" on the back-end (server.jsx and so on -> server.js), using console.log to figure out what was going on, and then just gut feeling the fix. That works on a smaller scale, but will be problematic in time.

I can debug both of the actual files, but only app.js is ever mapped properly, meaning I can debug the source code. This also affects hot loading. Any breakpoints related to server.js will only trigger in the actual server.js file in IntelliJ, which is a completely unreadable mesh, so that's not really an option.

I'm using IntelliJ (WebStorm for those of you who only use the web version), and I've tried to use every single guide I've come across to set it up, which usually comes down to babel-node, babel watchers or webpack-dev-server. The current app.js is run using webpack-dev-middleware, and debugging it in Chrome works like a charm, but for some reason it always just bundles in server.js and then fires when ready (in these Star Wars times).

I understand that it's hard for Chrome to get access to server.jsx, but surely there must be some way of setting up IntelliJ (or WebStorm) to do so? I'm more used to a Java or C# server side, so I'm a bit baffled that this isn't a straight forward, out-of-the-box option. Or maybe it is, and the initial setup is lacking?

*PS. When using React (and Redux) as both the front and back end on Node, is it meant to be virtually impossible to distinguish between the two? Server.jsx is fairly obvious, but there are quite a few duplicated javascript files and dependancies, especially related to handling/building the Redux store.*

Comment: Just a small update: I still haven't been able to debug it, but from what I can tell, it's primarily based on this tutorial: 
https://medium.com/front-end-developers/handcrafting-an-isomorphic-redux-application-with-love-40ada4468af4#.oh7nv9yi7

The server.jsx file is almost identical, as is the way needs [] etc works. Too bad the tutorial doesn't mention server-side debugging.

Comment: Look into Jest, Chai-http, Mockito, and other testing frameworks. Jest to make sure your components are being rendered correctly, and chai to make sure that your backend is working properly